# org.json.simple. get unique nested value

Tags: java, json

I have a json with complex nested. values.   But there is one unique key value pair in the json.. without traversing  , I need to retrieve the value .

for example:

name : "xyz".    In the entire complex nested json ,  I need to return a json with all the values of name key.

I am currently using org.simple.json.  but its very complex as I have to traverse through the entire nested json and build JSONArray etc.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use java8 stream，the way is very easy to solve your problem.

example：

```
[
    {
        "name":"xyz",
        "value":"1"
    },
    {
        "name":"xyz",
        "value":"2"
    },
    {
        "name":"xyz",
        "value":"3"
    }
]
```

and then，you can create a class:

```java
import lombok.Data;


@Data
public class JsonTest {
    
    private String name;
    
    private String value;
}
```

finally, like this.  btw, I am currently using other json package.

```
 List<JsonTest> jsonArray = JSON.parseArray(json, JsonTest.class);
        List<String> valueList = jsonArray.stream()
                .filter(e -> "xyz".equals(e.getName()))
                .map(JsonTest::getValue)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```